# Probability of having HIV in NYC

Tags: probability

The probability of a randomly selected newborn from New York City being HIV positive is 0.0124 and that the probability of a randomly selected newborn from “upstate New York” (i.e., from New York State but not from New York City) being infected with HIV is 0.0017.

Given that $40.7$% of the population of New York State lives in New York City, calculate the probability that a randomly selected newborn from New York State ****is HIV positive.**

**I believe it is as simple as $0.0124\times0.407=.005\times100= 0.5$% but I am not positive.**

Comment: if ur already sure ur not positive then whats the point?

Comment: $0.0124\times 0.407\neq .005\times 100$

Comment: $0.0124*0.407+0.0017*0.493=0.0058849$

Comment: Where did you get 0.493 from?

Comment: It looks like Robert Z meant to write $0.0124 \cdot 0.407 + 0.0017 \cdot 0.593$, where $0.593 = 1 - 0.407$.